# Present `UIViewController` in iPhone as we have in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to present a `UIViewController` in iPhone and iPad both as same as we present in iPad using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` but i also want to give good amount of curve on the edges like cornerRadius. I can do it using `UIView` and animate it from bottom to top but i want to do using `UIViewController`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible using the built-in frameworks.

> [**Docs**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/uimodalpresentationformsheet):
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as
>   `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.

You'll have to write custom code to show a view modally that doesn't fully obscure the underlying view.

Comment: Yes, Will be very helpful if you can tell some Custom FrameWork? Thanks.

Comment: That's the first I found https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController

Comment: Yap Thanks this might help me